# 'module' is undefined in grunt javascript

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, build-script

I want to integrate Grunt on my java Script project. I have installed npm, grunt and all.

I have created the package.json file and GRUNTFILE.js for the grunt.

but when i run the "grunt" command i am getting this error 'module' is undefined.

GRUNTFILE.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', []);



};
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "Example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "latest",
    "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13"
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you aren't actually running Node.

Comment: node is running on machine.

Comment: Did you run 'npm install' in the directory where your grunt configuration files are stored ?

Comment: Ya, I run the 'npm install' on my project directory but still error is same.

Answer (score 11):

I also had this problem I found that making sure you have correctly named the grunt file to `Gruntfile.js` fixed my problem, silly but can be overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

After running following command I am successfully run the grunt on my project.

1. npm uninstall
2. npm install -g grunt-cli (which install globally)
3. npm install (On a Project directory)

Before running the third commend project must contain 'packge.json' and gruntfile.js files.